# Copying string to char array quickly

Tags: c#, string, input

I need to read a string from standard input, perform some operations and meanwhile I need to copy some of input to char array.
In C++ I could do it like this:

```
scanf("%s", &array[pos]);
```

which copies string `s` to char `array` at position `pos`. 
I need to do do this very quickly (olympic task).
Reading from one big while in C++ took 5 sec.
On C# I tried copying to array using `string.elementAt()` in a loop but it took 70 seconds, which is way too much. Also, building one big string and than using string.ToCharArray() is a bad idea.
Any ideas how to do that?

```
char[] ciag = new char[1010001];
for(int x = 0 ; x < n ; x++){
line = Console.ReadLine();
sekw[x] = poz;
len = int.Parse(line.Split(' ')[0]);  //length of string to copy
string znaki = line.Split(' ')[1];    //copied string
for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
{
ciag[poz + j] = znaki[j];  //put into array. Perhaps slow.
}
poz += len;
ciag[poz++] = 'k';  //my stuff
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `scanf` isn't very much C++, it's actually inherited from its C roots. In C++ you would use e.g. `std::cin >> &array[pos];`.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do on the C# side.

Comment: Sorry not the time to give a precise answer, so a comment must do. You definetely want to check the StringBuilder. A String is immutable so you can't change it, thats why your operations take that long. You always recreate a new string. A stringbuilder is better for high frequent changes to strings.

Comment: Have you tried reading it from a stream directly?

Comment: there are some easy to make mistakes that would slow this down. please post you c# code.

Comment: Here is the code.                                                    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
            {
                line = Console.ReadLine();
                sekw[x] = poz;
                len = int.Parse(line.Split(' ')[0]); //length of string I want to copy
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                {
                    string znaki = line.Split(' ')[1]; //string to copy
                    ciag[poz + j] = znaki[j];
                }
                poz += len;
                ciag[poz++] = 'k'; //my stuff
            }            I will try string builder

Comment: Mayble string.Split() is that slow? As I said there are 100 char arrays of length up to 10000.

Comment: String.Split is accessing every char once... and you do it two times... but i in general dont get what you are doing there, can you edit it once more and make a compiling mini project out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void CopyTo(
    int sourceIndex,
    char[] destination,
    int destinationIndex,
    int count
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
char[] c = new char[stringa.Length];   

for(int i = 0;i<stringa.Length;i++){
     c[i] = stringa[i];
}
```

I'm not really sure it will improve the performance though. Although clearly explaining what you need would really help

Comment: of course, it has to be O(n) if you're going to copy the whole string

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
using (Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    stdin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    char[] inputCharArray = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetChars(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder`.

This code processes 100 x 10000 characters in about one second.
If you need it faster you can make your tasks parallel using the TPL - Task Parallel Library from namespace: System.Threading.Tasks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] input = CreateInput();
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                StringCutter(new String(input));
            }
            Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - start).ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static char[] CreateInput()
        {
            const int len = 10000;
            char[] ret = new char[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                ret[i] = Convert.ToChar(i % 256);
            }
            return ret;
        }

        private static String StringCutter(String str)
        {
            List<char> exclusion = new List<char> { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!(exclusion.Contains(result[i])))
                {
                    result.Remove(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder is also too slow (when It has to create string that constist of 100 char arrays of lenthg up to 10000).

Comment: I improved the handling of the chars to work directly on the Stringbuilder instead of iterating through a String. Also i added your specification of 100x10000 chars and took the time - the code above finishes in one second.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            line = Console.ReadLine();
            sekw[x] = poz;
            len = int.Parse(line.Split(' ')[0]);
            char[] temp = line.Split(' ')[1].ToCharArray();
            **Array.Copy(temp, 0, ciag, poz, temp.Length);** 
            poz += len;
            ciag[poz++] = 'k';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

`char[] Words = "Exemple string test".ToCharArray();`

`char[] Words = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();`